# Difference between manually file import and pod installation in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, ios-library

I want to know what is exact process behind the xcode, when we add thirdparty library or framework using directly drag & drop the folder into out xcode project, which is manually process. and we use the command prompt to install the pod of particular library or framework.

Please explain me these both process, if anyone know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804692/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-cocoapods 

The answer to this might answer your question.