# Can one use these podfile instructions together?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoapods

Here is the podfile for application # 1 in which the deployment target has ben updated to 9.0. It was originally created 5 years ago in the golden age of iOS development circa iOS 7.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 1.2.0'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.6'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'MessageBanner', '~> 1.0'
```

Here is another set of instructions from another application's podfile.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'NameOfApp' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'Cards'


end
```

I notice the contrasts in the syntax of the 2 podfiles, specifically the

```
target 'NameOfApp' do
use_frameworks!
```

Will running

```
pod install
```

or

```
pod update
```

After successfully combining the podfiles, successfully achieve cocoa pod functionality in this situation or would a drag-and-drop of the podsfile's group content and files work when dropped into the new app?

[image]

Which method would be more scalable?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question. COuld you please be more specific? Are you asking about the usage of target '' in podfile or what do you mean by drag-drop ?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I should have been more clear. I find it easier to manually drag files from existing Xcode projects into new Xcode projects that I'd like to see the functionality in. I was debating whether or not to use this method for the pod functionality I'd like to use or whether to use the terminal and commands.

Comment: So you have project 'X' with some pods installed , and you want to drag and drop them into other projects instead of installing pods again ?

Comment: Yes. Either or. Whichever helps the new Xcode application find the new files easier.

Comment: It could work , it doesnt matter for xcode whether you supply dependecies by pods or  you directly add the files to xcode.  Ideally you should not do it manually. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804692/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-cocoapods

Comment: Running `pod install` should be fine. Refer to the getting started section on: https://cocoapods.org/